# Read the contents of a requested file without saving it in Ktor [Kotlin]

Tags: java, kotlin, multipartform-data, ktor

Is it possible to read the contents of a file directly without having to save it. The file (.json) is received as a multipart request. This example was used for [orientation](https://ktor.io/docs/requests.html#form_data).

Instead of saving the file as in the example, its content is to be saved directly in a map.

With the following line I get the fileBytes.

```kotlin
var fileBytes = part.streamProvider().readBytes()
```

How to read the content of the file from the fileBytes

Comment: What is the format of the file? You would have to decode whatever is in that file into actual runtime instances. This process is called deserialization, and it completely depends on how the data was written (serialized) into this file in the first place

Comment: The `fileBytes` already refers to the content (byte array) of a file. Probably, you want to convert (deserialize) this content to a map by interpreting an array of bytes as JSON. You can do this by using a serialization/deserialization framework, e.g. https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization.